# Tkinter Python AWS Cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, tkinter, aws-cloud9

is there the possibility to import Tkinter modul in IDE AWS Cloud9 (Python)?
This simple program doesn't work (No module name 'Tkinter').
Any suggestion?
Thanks

```
from tkinter import Label # get a widget 
object
widget = Label(None, text='Hello GUI 
world!') # make one
widget.pack() # arrange it
widget.mainloop() # start event loop
```

Comment: Which one did you use in your code actually: `Tkinter` or `tkinter`?

Comment: both of them (it doesn't work bot with Tkinter and tkinter)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked tkinter is sucessfully installed or not?
check it by using `pip freeze`

if it is not installed then try this command
python3

> sudo apt-get install python3-tk

python2

> sudo apt-get install python-tk